# Looking for 64-bit msysgit

Tags: windows, 64-bit, git, msysgit

My git operations are failing when they hit the 4GB limit memory limit for 32-bit processes.

```
E:\source>file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe; PE32 executable for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit
```

As a result, git cannot do useful things like rebase.

```
E:\source>git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 163954 bytes)

git encountered an error while preparing the patches to replay
these revisions:

    4bc5ce781c5749307637481f76e45134989cce56..b0d91ccc3714e31e2d2487906f6719b3f71dc064
```

I've looked at the [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) website, but the installers all seem to be for the 32-bit version. I do occasionally see references to a 64-bit version in the release notes.

My searching has failed to turn up the 64-bit Windows installer. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/)’s Git package, it should be available in the 64-bit Cygwin version—along with many other great Linux-y tools. It’s also worth mentioning that it’s much more up-to-date, supports proper TLS 1.2 with PFS and whatnot.

Comment: I'll use this if there's no other option. I'd strongly prefer to avoid cygwin because I hate having to change all my configuration files to `/cygdrive/c/...` and god forbid it see a slash pointed the wrong way or try to invoke a Win32 editor with a Linux style path.

Comment: Nah, Cygwin can resolve Windows paths just fine, though it'll probably complain a lot. ;) I use it with Git Extensions for example.